# Adding specific id attribute as labels in graph in igraph

Tags: r, igraph, label, vertices, sna

I need to add the id attribute to my vertices as labels, and display them in the plot. Which I did with the following code:

```
V(novel)$label <- V(novel)$id
plot(novel)
```

However, I only want to display the id of the vertices where the weighted degree is more than 30. I tried the code below, but it gives me only `TRUE` or `FALSE` as output, instead of filtering the vertices.

```
graph.strength(novel) > 30
```

How can I filter in which vertices should the plot display the id?

Answer (score 1):

`V(novel)$label <- ifelse(graph.strength(novel) > 30, V(novel)$id, "")` should do the trick; basically you set up an empty label for those vertices that have a strength less than or equal to 30.